# Is this subset of $PSL(n,\mathbb{R})$ Zariski-closed?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

For some non-identity element $[A]\in PSL(n,\mathbb{R})$ ($[A]$ being the class of $A\in SL(n,\mathbb{R})$) and linearly independent vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, let $[x],[y]$ denote the classes of $x$ and $y$ in the projective space $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$. We then define
$$X=\{s\in PSL(n,\mathbb{R})\,|\,s[A]s^{-1}[x]=[y]\}.$$
My question is:

> Is $X$ Zariski-closed in $PSL(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Clearly its pre-image in $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is
$$\{B\in SL(n,\mathbb{R})\,|\,BAB^{-1}x\in\mathbb{R}^\times y\},$$
but that subset does not look Zariski-closed to me. (I really need it to be.) I have a feeling that it might boil down to the subset $$\{B\in SL(n,\mathbb{R})\,|\,BAB^{-1}x=y\},$$ which is clearly the zero set of $n$ real $n^2$-variable polynomials, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the polynomial map $f : \operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R}) \to \wedge^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined by $f(B) = (BAB^{-1}x) \wedge y$. Observe that since $Cx \neq 0$ for all $C \in \operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, we have $f(B) = 0$ if and only if $BAB^{-1}x \in \mathbb{R}^\times y$. Therefore, the pre-image of $X$ in $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is the vanishing set of $\binom{n}{2}$ homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in the entries of $B$. Hence, $X$ is Zariski-closed in $\operatorname{PSL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: What does $\wedge^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ mean?

Comment: Sorry, this is the second exterior power of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Probably, I should also have mentioned that if $u = (u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ and $w = (w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the coordinates of their wedge product $u \wedge w$ in the 'standard' basis of $\wedge^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \simeq \mathbb{R}^{\binom{n}{2}}$ are $u_iw_j - u_jw_i$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq n$, i.e. all possible $2\times 2$ minors of the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & \ldots & u_n \\ w_1 & w_2 & \ldots & w_n\end{pmatrix},$$ and thus $u \wedge w = 0$ if and only if $u$ and $w$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: One more question: what do you mean by "polynomial map"? I'm sorry that I need to have it spelled out -- but does it just mean that when writing $f(B)$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}^{\binom{n}{2}}$, then each coordinate is a polynomial in $B$? And why is that?

Comment: I really appreciate this, by the way. :)

Comment: And now I realize you just told me, duh. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.